# Select text values too long. How to make it fit in select size

Tags: html

the options values is too long. I want to make those value to fit in combobox size. No matter if it takes two or 3 line.

How can i do that..

Any Help..

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a multi-lines combobox in HTML. I recommand you do it using a div that acts like a select, using Javascript/jQuery & CSS.

EDIT : here is a [tutorial](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) that may help you, demo [here](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/index.html).